# Android Studio - First Aplication

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm begginer in coding and I start to create my first apk for android in Android Studio watching a video from youtube, but today I had some problems with this. I want to install SmoothBottomBar 1.7.9 but I have this errors.
Please help me, I have no idea how to solve this.

**This is what I added in activity_main:**

```
<me.ibrahimsn.lib.SmoothBottomBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    app:backgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/menu" />
```

**And this are the errors:**

Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project C:\Users\vioad\Desktop\Quiz Game

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeDebugMetadata NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugAarMetadata FAILED
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
> Task :app:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:parseDebugLocalResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets FAILED
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource FAILED
> Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses FAILED
> Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies FAILED
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs FAILED
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugAppMetadata UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugSigningConfigVersions UP-TO-DATE

FAILURE: Build completed with 8 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.github.ibrahimsn98:SmoothBottomBar:1.7.9.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.github.ibrahimsn98:SmoothBottomBar:1.7.9.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

### 3: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.github.ibrahimsn98:SmoothBottomBar:1.7.9.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

### 4: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.github.ibrahimsn98:SmoothBottomBar:1.7.9.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

### 5: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.github.ibrahimsn98:SmoothBottomBar:1.7.9.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

### 6: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.github.ibrahimsn98:SmoothBottomBar:1.7.9.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

### 7: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:desugarDebugFileDependencies'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.github.ibrahimsn98:SmoothBottomBar:1.7.9.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

### 8: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.github.ibrahimsn98:SmoothBottomBar:1.7.9.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  ==============================================================================

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

BUILD FAILED in 1s
20 actionable tasks: 8 executed, 12 up-to-date

Comment: https://github.com/ibrahimsn98/SmoothBottomBar/issues/98
This may help?

Comment: I did it, but doesn't work unfortunetly :(

Answer (score 3):

Please look at the bottom section of the `README.md` file found [here](https://github.com/ibrahimsn98/SmoothBottomBar/blob/master/README.md).

The errors you are having are being caused by not adding the library in the repository block inside `build.gradle (project)`.

You also need this Library's dependency implementation which should be added under the dependency section inside the `build.gradle (app)` file.

Please see these code snippets from the `README.md` file

***build.gradle (project) file***

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.0.5'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

        //add this line
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
```

***build.gradle (app) file***

```
dependencies {
    //add this dependency in the dependencies section
    implementation 'com.github.ibrahimsn98:SmoothBottomBar:1.7.9'
    
    
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0' ....}
```

Please also read the other details of the [READM.md](https://github.com/ibrahimsn98/SmoothBottomBar/blob/master/README.md) on how to set-up the Library.